# page won't show video from youtube

Tags: html, css

why can't i see the video, it just show a white space. (i edited the link of the video)
if i check the video on youtube its fine.

if i right click on the white space it says "movie not loaded" but even if i wait doesn't happen anything. i also uploaded the video on the ftp of the website, can i just load it from there? how?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px auto; text-align:center; color:white;" >

<div id="container" style="margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;" >

<div id="main" style="width:100%;margin:0px auto;">
        <div id="hdr" style="background-image:url(bg.jpg);float:left;width:100%;height:110px;">
        </div>
        <div id="hdr2" style="background-image:url(fascia.png);float:left;width:100%;height:70px;">
            footer
        </div>
        <div id="bdy" style="background-image:url(bg.jpg);float:left;width:100%;height:70px;">
            body
        </div>
        <div id="ftr" style="background-image:url(bg.jpg);float:left;width:100%;height:500px;">

<object width="640" height="360"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxx"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxx" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>

        </div>
        <div id="ftr2" style="background-image:url(bg.jpg);float:left;width:100%;height:280px;">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you dont use youtube video url as iframe method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Hopes this helps!